# Solving 2D non-homogeneous wave equation

Tags: differential

Solve the 2D non-homogeneous wave equation assuming that the boundary condition on the space is that  for over the square boundary of the 2D surface. Also the condition on the time dependent part is . The wave has a sinusoidal source of a certain frequency given as . Make a graph and animation of the solution.

I solved the homogeneous part using variation of parameters.I don't know how to solve the inhomogeneous part .Do we have to use fourier trick to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: oh ok..thanks will edit it